как сделать сохранения данных пользователя на сайте без его регистрации и авторизации на нем
Я сейчас делаю сайт на DRF и React для теста скорости печати и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь заходит на сайт, ему не надо регистрироваться, он сразу вводит текст и результат его скорости сохраняется в профиле, но если он выйдет с сайта (закроет его) и снова откроет с того же браузера и того же устройства, то его данные о скорости печати и о количестве текста сохранятся. Пример как тут: https://blindtyping.com

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie

Еще варианты: Хранение данных в браузере

В реакте можно хранить данные в браузере
localStorage.setItem("progress", "complete")
localStorage.getItem("progress")

Так же вы можете в браузере хранить id сессси, случайно сгененированный id и по нему на бэкенде хранить данные
